# Can there be a step function and a normal function for the .animate() callback in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, callback, jquery-animate

I'm trying to use a step: function to make my "tab" div and an "options" div slide out at the same time (i.e., sync the animation of the two divs), but I also need a regular function for the animation.

Is it possible to have both of these types of functions as the callback function for .animate()?

Edit:

[Test page](http://students.cmps.subr.edu/aaron.chauvin/misc/test.html)

On the above test page, I'm wanting to make another div slide out on click of the "text tab" in the upper left corner, BUT according to the jQuery .animate() docs, the step: function is used to sync the animation of different elments and I'm here is my JS:

```
$( "#optsdiv" ).hide();
$( "#closediv" ).hide();
$( "#opendiv" ).click( function() {
  $( "#opendiv" ).animate( { left: "+=100px", opacity: 1 }, 1400, "easeOutExpo", function() {
     $( "#opendiv" ).hide();
     $( "#opendiv" ).animate( { left: "-=100px", opacity: 0.6 }, 0 );
     $( "#closediv" ).show();
    });
});

$( "#closediv" ).click( function() {
  $( "#closediv" ).animate( { left: "-=100px", opacity: 0.6 }, 1400, "easeOutExpo", function() {
    $( "#opendiv" ).show();
    $( "#closediv" ).hide();
    $( "#closediv" ).animate( { left: "+=100px", opacity: 1 }, 0 );
   });
});
```

As you can see, I use a "normal" function (a non-step: function) to finish up the animations... so I was wondering if I could still use the function I'm currently using while implementing the step: function in the same callback so as to sync the sliding out of the tab and the other div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by *"regular function"*, you mean a callback at the end of the animation, then yes, just set all the properties of the animation using the second *options* argument:

```
$('.someElement').animate({width:100}, { duration:1000,
                                         step: function(){},
                                         complete: function(){} });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/n2pZp/1/

Comment: But can I have a step: function AND a "regular" function for the callback _at the same time_?

Comment: @Aaron: Either I don't know what you mean by a "regular" function, or I don't know what you mean by "at the same time". Are you saying you want the `step:` function to invoke another function?

Comment: I need the step: function as the callback for .animate() in order to sync the animation of multiple divs but I ALSO need a standard (non-step:) function as the callback to perform other post-animation effects. Is this possible?

Comment: @Aaron: It just sounds like you're saying that you need one function to run as the step callback, and a different one to run after the animation is complete. But then that's what my answer gives, so I'm obviously still not understanding you. Please update your question with some code (even a simple example to illustrate what you want), or create a jsFiddle as I did in my answer.

Comment: ...and if you're just doing this to synchronize the animations of some other elements, then why not just give them their own `.animate()` with the same duration?

Comment: I'll try the 1st of your suggestions, but in my interpretation of the jQuery .animate() documentation, it seems that any post animation effects should be handled with the call back function so as to allow for a seemless transition. If I sync with a step function in the callback, then do the post animation effects, I'm thinking there will be an undesired lag between animation effects.

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, but the `$(...).animate({...},{complete:function(){...}})` callback is the exact same as the regular callback `$(...).animate({...}, function(){})`, so I'm a little confused as to what the issue is. If somehow it doesn't work for you, then please post a code example to illustrate what you're doing.

Comment: @Aaron: Is it the `#optsdiv` that you're trying to coordinate with the `#opendiv`?

Comment: @Patrick, yes, that is the div I'm going to try to slide right/left along with `#opendiv`/`#closediv`

Comment: @Aaron: With your current HTML, it doesn't seem that you'd need the `step` callback to coordinate the two. Just do a separate (parallel) animation on the `#optsdiv` that starts at the same time, and has the same duration as the `#opendiv` animation. Better yet, change your HTML and CSS so that you have both in a single container. Then you can just animate the container, and both will move along with it.

Comment: @Patrick, OMG... thanks so much. I'm really runnin' empty man. I should've realized that! I always get like this when I'm tired, lol.

Comment: @Aaron: You're not alone! Glad I could help. :o)

Comment: @Patrick: Worked great! Thanks so much again!!! Now to settle on an easing & add the text altering options to #optsdiv...